# How to return a dictionary through a `UnsafeMutablePointer<CFTypeRef?>?` parameter?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, foundation

For tests I created a mock class which wraps the `Security` framework functions. Everything works fine except for **my attempted fake of [`SecItemCopyMatching(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1398306-secitemcopymatching)**. The full signature is:

```
func SecItemCopyMatching(_ query: CFDictionary, _ result: UnsafeMutablePointer<CFTypeRef?>?) -> OSStatus
```

**I do not want to use `SecItemCopyMatching(_:_:)`** of the `Security` framework but **implement a dummy with the same signature** for testing by myself.

The following snippet is from [the official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/keychain_services/keychain_items/searching_for_keychain_items) on how to process the functions result. I do not know how to render a dummy Dictionary through the `UnsafeMutablePointer` to be used the same way. I cannot assign anything to the pointer and am confused by the `UnsafeMutablePointer<CFTypeRef?>?` - is that a pointer to a pointer?

```
guard let existingItem = item as? [String : Any],
    let passwordData = existingItem[kSecValueData as String] as? Data,
    let password = String(data: passwordData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8),
    let username = existingItem[kSecAttrAccount as String] as? String
    else {
        throw KeychainError.unexpectedPasswordData
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The working solution I found:

```
func SecItemCopyMatching(_ query: CFDictionary, _ result: UnsafeMutablePointer<CFTypeRef?>?) -> OSStatus {
    let item: [String: Any] = [
        kSecAttrAccount as String: "username",
        kSecValueData as String: "password".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    ]

    result?.pointee = item as AnyObject
    return copyMatchingStatus
}
```

They key information to understand: `CFTypeRef` maps directly to `AnyObject` (see [Working with Core Foundation Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/working_with_core_foundation_types)). Casting the dictionary to `AnyObject` enables assignment as a pointee.